# I want to make my own source code editor, what are the good choices to make?

Tags: c++, qt, notepad++, scintilla, qtextedit

I've had it of those dozens of editors which never provides simple things like:

- distinguish type keywords and instruction keywords so I can put different colors on them.
- being cross platform using a standard GUI lib like qt gtk etc (notepad++, yes, I almost hate you).
- enough keyboard shortcut like duplicate line, comment selection, and a decent find-replace.
- Decent task-easing features like single-click-on-the-number-line-margin to select the entire line.
- Scintilla or another good-enough lexer that highlights enough different things, because brain-compiling code is one thing, quickly identify with the eyes what is what is something I find important.

I just want to support very basic languages like C, C++, maybe Python, not HTML or CSS.

Is Scintilla a good choice to just highlight those languages, and is a lexer really necessary ?

Isn't QT enough to program a text editor such as the one I want to do ? I know there is QScintilla, but is there a reason I shouldn't use a lib that integrates a lexer ? Why is Scintilla such a good lib ?

Is QT a good choice for such an editor ? (I also want to hard embed ProFont in the editor to kill any reluctant font problem between OSes).

EDIT:
In short, I want to make an editor, only with the same syntax highlight features of notepad++. That's my main goal, and the use of QScintilla might be a little harder than I thought...

EDIT2:
Well I found textadept, it's not so known but is quite awesome. I didn't manage to make my lexer, since I have other to do which I do under windows, unfortunately it's slow on the mac. Apparently there isn't any Scite official build for the mac.

Comment: It's funny because I've seen all of these features on the editors I've used, so what is the problem? Not having a single one that works on every platform? I'm confused what you're having an issue with the current ones that you couldn't work with (for example) the codebase for Eclipse and modify it to do what you want...

Comment: Eclipse ? that's an IDE not an editor...

Comment: Eclipse is not an IDE, it's a software platform and a code base, used - among others - for IDEs.

Comment: well I might look on how it does syntax highlightning...

Comment: I've had success running Notepad++ through Wine in Linux, but I haven't used it a lot, since I primarily edit with The One True Editor (Vim).

Comment: Here I found interesting project in QT (C++): https://github.com/Megaxela/QCodeEditor/ unfortunately the project is not being updated for long time, but community are making proposals, e.g. compatibility with Qt6: https://github.com/Megaxela/QCodeEditor/pull/47

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like everyone else is saying, it's probably more trouble than it's worth, but if you really want to do it, Qt's a good choice since it's cross platform. Use QSyntaxHighlighter to do your keyword/type highlighting, and take full advantage Qt's support for keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Isn't QScintilla more powerful ?

Comment: Probably; I've never used it. Looks nice.

Answer (score 6):

C++ is not a "very basic language" by any stretch of the imagination.

Why do you really want to do this? There are SOOO many open source code editors out there.

Comment: It's essentially because I want an editor that looks nice to the eye: I just can't let go a dark background editor with the colors I want... The main reason I want to do this, is I'm tired of always configuring an editor I like to something I like, plus, the features I am looking for are quite simple, and always a pain to make work in an existing editor, and it's always frustrating to see all the advanced feature on an editor, without finding the simple thing that I like. I'm a nerd I know, I have my stupid standards but if I can make an editor that would be nice, especially cross platform...

Comment: I can't personally think of a less basic language than C++

Comment: @gokoon: wouldn't it be easier to find an editor which supports the features you need, configure it for your tastes once and for all, **and then save the configuration files**? That way you might be able to get away with, say, 1 hours work, instead of a couple of man-years.

Comment: I was saying basic, I wanted to say I just want to support it, as in "popular language" and not support all kind of language like lisp python java ocaml php ruby etc, just C++. For the configuration files, that's not enough, notepad++ is not running on a mac natively, and I prefer hard coding some behaviours because sometimes they make more sense. That should ease the task a lot.

Comment: @gokoon: I just can't believe that your needs for a code editor are different to everybody else's.

Answer (score 5):

If you must write your own editor, I suggest looking at the other open source editors and examine which pieces you port to your editor.

Porting pieces of existing working and tested code is usually much better than writing your own code and debugging it.

After perusing a couple serious open source editors:  Emacs, Eclips, CodeBlocks, CodeLight, etc., I believe you will start changing your mind about writing an editor from scratch.

-- Thomas Matthews
[My Info](http://members.cox.net/thomas_matthews/Resume/resume.html)

Comment: the editors you quote are full-featured IDE, I just want to make some kind of simple notepad with syntax highlighting, a thing scintilla does... and Qt might help a lot...

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to do this (and it sounds like a lot of work) I would look at ANTLR for parsing the code. You may get some ideas from their ANTLRWorks display. 
To link the parse tree to a display could be a fair amount of work so I'd see what an IDE platform such as Eclipse has to offer

Answer (score 1):

Are you OK with Java?

If so, go for Eclipse technologies: **[SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) and [JFace](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/JFace)**. The latter provides you with **`org.eclipse.jface.text`** package with a lot of features. Then you can roll own editor easily basing on that. *(I prefer Eclipse-based editors to Scintilla-based, I believe they tend to be more advanced and feature-rich, but that's my personal opinion.)*

But then, you might want to go a step further and use the [Eclipse RCP framework](http://www.eclipse.org/rcp/) for you application... But then why not use the Eclipse IDE itself and just add whatever you want as plug-ins.

The Eclipse codebase is huge and it's up to you how much you want to reuse.

Comment: java is politically not very ok with me. It might be ok if I would focus on windows, but that's not the case.

Answer (score 1):

I would expend some effort experimenting with the emacs colour theme package and the various langauge modes; see if you can bend the lisp to do what you want. You almost certainly can. to my mind emacs and a bit of effort on your part will get you your ultimate editor (remember emacs is really just a DIY editor toolkit). If you cant bend emacs into the shape you want you will be well placed to expend the effort in writing your own.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to do something similar myself for a project I'm working on at the moment, I looked into the `QScintilla` and had to remove it from my project because when you embedded inside a `QGraphicsView` I can't control the resolution of the widgets image, it seems to paint the text as an image and that's what we see, I played with increasing the smoothness of the `QFont` and that improved it but still a no-go.

So I found a simple code editor inside QT's code base it comes with every installation of QT if you look 
into:

```
C:\Qt\4.7.3\src\scripttools\debugging\qscriptedit.h
C:\Qt\4.7.3\src\scripttools\debugging\qscriptedit.cpp
```

If you go to the source code of `OpenShapeFactory` where I'm trying to embed a Code Editor: check how I got the syntax Highlighter and the autocomplete :

this widget uses the qscriptedit widget that ships with qt, you can add your own keywords to the syntax hightlighter from a file as well as for the auto-complete dropdownlist.

this is the header, [scriptwidget.h](http://code.google.com/p/openshapefactory/source/browse/SFMQTGUI/scriptwidget.h) and the implementation [scriptwidget.cpp](http://code.google.com/p/openshapefactory/source/browse/SFMQTGUI/scriptwidget.cpp) are available as part of the whole [project code](http://code.google.com/p/openshapefactory).

the next stage is to look into the QTCreator and see the code they already have all if not most of these features after you get to compile their version, just find where to add your little mods and you might be getting closer to the simple code editor.

I wish you the best of luck on this direction and if you find a solution please send it over, :)
heads-up keep a lookout for the repository link above, if I find a way of making it first, I might chase you to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

use something like C, QT and Lua for the scripting engine.

Comment: It's what textadept does, without QT, and it's sloooow. I've given up, mainly because cross-platform text coloring and editing is high level and low level at the same time, and thus, too complicated. I might look at wx widget and look at what I can use, but the main issue is obviously the lexer and color handling. I wonder if I could do something nice with HTML5 and last gen browsers.